# Law of conservation of momentum , elastic collision

Tags: classical-mechanics, momentum

In Law of Conservation of momentum , elastic collision 
occurs only in an isolated system. 
A case defined as,when 
Object A comes with initial velocity and collides with object B which is in rest V= 0 then B moves with the velocity of A. (both having same masses ) 
My question is that if this law occurs in an isolated system, where there is no gravity then how is it possible that an object is in rest ?

Answer (score 0):

An object can be at rest in space, infinitely away from any other massive body.

Comment: Rest due to a force ..                    If  a body can be at rest in space so which force remain it in rest ?? How rest

Comment: A is brought to rest because of the force B exerts on A during the collision. Which is also equal but opposite in direction to the force that A exerts on B.